# Importing and compiling a module with wasm into webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, webassembly

I'm trying to import a [module](https://github.com/silvia-odwyer/photon) for use within a library which is compiled through webpack. Although the javascript API from the module is loaded, the accompanying `.wasm` file is not and causes any functions mentioning the `wasm` module to throw undefined errors. There is also the possibility that webpack is interfering with the `.wasm` file but I'm not sure. Here is the error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _index_bg_wasm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.open_image is not a function
    at Module.open_image (index_bg.js?0d72:1468)
```

And the associated function call

```
import('@silvia-odwyer/photon').then(photon => {
  console.log(photon.open_image) // <-- correctly prints function
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let photonImg = photon.open_image(canvas, ctx); // <-- error
  photon.grayscale(photonImg);
  photon.putImageData(canvas, ctx, photonImg);
});
```

I have tried using `wasm-loader`, editing my `tsconfig` to use `esnext` according to [this](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/700), writing in javascript instead of typescript, limiting the webpack chunk count to 1, and different ways of importing and compiling wasm from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API) and [online](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7352)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this exact same error, and it actually happened because I was double-loading the WASM file. In my webpack config I had my wasm-pack config:

```js
config.plugin('wasm-pack')
    .use(WasmPackPlugin)
    .init(
      (Plugin) =>
        new Plugin({
          crateDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, './rust_wasm_code'),
          forceMode: 'release'
        })
    )
    .end()
```

as well as file-loading code for loading WASM files:

```js
config.module
    .rule('wasm')
    .test(/.wasm$/)
    .use('wasm-loader')
    .loader('wasm-loader')
```

I fixed the error by removing the second piece of code (and relying on WASM-pack to compile and load).